# How do you calculate negative powers in C using iteration?

Tags: c, iteration, pow

I'm writing a function in C that takes in a float base and int power, and calculates base^power

So far I have:

```
float powIteration(float base, int power){
    if (power == 0){
        return 1;
    }
    else if (power > 0){
         for (int i = 0; i <= power; i++){
            base *= base;
       }
        return base;
    }
    else if (power < 0){
        for (int i = 0; i <= power; i++){
            base *= base;
        }
        return 1/base;
    }
}
```

I've already solved this using recursion. But I also want to do it using iteration. But for some reason, this code results in stuff like 2^-2 = 0.5

Furthermore, would this method even fulfill what would be called an "iterative approach"?

Comment: `i <= power` How many times do you expect that `for` loop to run if `power < 0`?

Comment: seems to me that loop should be < power, not <=. I fact maybe even < power - 1. If power = 1 you want no multiplies, if power = 2 then you want 1 loop..

Comment: Oh shoot you're right. Is there a way around that? Or does the structure of the code need to change?

Comment: power = -power will fix that

Comment: i mean your positive power doesnt work, f(2.0,2) gives 256, you need to remeber the original base too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered the last one instantly just by the first mistake I found, so I figured I'd go test and help you out with this.

Firstly you are changing your `base` each iteration, and you don't want that, else you won't have a value to multiply every time, but one different every iteration. Just like pm100 said: you have to remember your original base. example: using `base=2` and `power=-3`:

```
i=0 -> base *= base; 2*2 = 4;
i=1 -> now base is 4 so: 4*4 = 16;
i=2 -> now base is 8 so: 8*8 = 64; and you want it to be 2*2*2
```

and finally `1/value` will give you the correct answer

Also in your negative for loop: You are making your for loop start at `0`, if your power is, let's say `-2`, then it doesn't meet your running condition `i <= power` because your `i` is always `> power`;
should make it something like this:

```
for (int i = power+1; i<0; i++)
```

I did some changes for you:

```
float powIteration(float base, int power){
    float num=base;
    if (power == 0){
        return 1;
    }else if (power > 0){
         for (int i = 1; i < power; i++){
            num=num*base;
       }
        return num;
    }else if (power < 0){
        for (int i = power+1; i<0; i++){
           num=num*base;
        }
        return 1/num;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Be carefull with this type of construct

```
if (...) { }
else if (...) { }
else if (...) { }
//   ^^^^^^^^      Why the 'if'? It should just be an 'else'
```

Your compiler could even warn you about it:

```
warning: non-void function does not return a value in all control paths [-Wreturn-type]
```

---

The loops are wrong in a couple of ways

```
else if (power > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= power; i++) {
    //                ^^   That's an off by one error. Likely.          
        base *= base;
    //  ^^^^^^             That's another algorithm. I'll show you later.
```

---

As already noted in the comments, another issue lies here

```
else if (power < 0) {
//       ^^^^^^^^^                        So, power is negative...
    for (int i = 0; i <= power; i++) {
    //       ^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^       But 'i' will never be.
```

That loop will never be executed, that's why you get 0.5 when the inputs are 2, -2.

---

There are many ways to complete this task.

```
double pow_iterative(double base, int power)
{
    if (power == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    // Use a variable different from base, to store the partials.
    double result = 1.0;

    // That's another approach, so that you can write a single loop.
    if ( power < 0 ) {
        base = 1.0 / base;
        power = -power;
    }

    // Note that we are modifying 'result', not base.
    for (int i = 0; i < power; ++i) {
        //           ^^^
        result *= base;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Another algorithm is called **exponentiation by squaring**

```
double pow_(double base, int power)
{
    double result = 1.0;
    if ( power < 0 ) {
        base = 1.0 / base;
        power = -power;
    }
    for(;;) {
        // If the power is odd, multiply once and "consume" the power
        //                     b^n = b * b^(n-1)
        if ( power % 2 ) {
            result *= base;
            --power; 
        }
        // It may have been consumed or 0 from the beginning
        if ( power == 0 )
            break;
        // The power is an even one, so we can square the base and halve the power
        //              b^(2n) = b^(n + n) = b^n * b^n = (b * b)^n
        base *= base;
        power /= 2;
    }
    return result;
}
```

You can try it [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/K2zy57yIIZjJX3D2).