# Is there a way to write summation using Scratch?

Tags: summary, mit-scratch

So I have recently been creating Cookie Clicker in Scratch. While I have been adding buildings to the game and a buy 10 function for those buildings, I honestly also want to add a Buy 100 function to the game but I don't want to have the code as `x+(x*1.15)+(x*1.15^2)+...+(x*1.15^99)`, where `x` is defined as the number of that building that the player currently has, and I honestly don't want to have to keep having to add 200+ blocks of code to the "Buy 10 of y" codes. (y in this case what building is being bought 10 times)
4 difficulties that are keeping me from solving this myself:

1. Scratch sadly doesn't have blocks to create less/greater than or equal to functions
2. Scratch doesn't have summation blocks
3. I honestly am terrible at coding, so I honestly just want a custom block that makes this easier.
4. Regular exponentiation doesn't exist in Scratch, but exponential notation (x*10^y) does.

As mentioned above (I've just been copying and pasting code at this point), I have to write it out as

if z (z being the number of the cookies the player has attained) = `x+(x*1.15)+(x*1.15*1.15)+(x*1.15*1.15*1.15)+(x*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15)+(x*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15)+(x*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15)+(x*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15)+(x*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15)+(x*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15) or if z > x+(x*1.15)+(x*1.15*1.15)+(x*1.15*1.15*1.15)+(x*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15)+(x*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15)+(x*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15)+(x*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15)+(x*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15)+(x*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15)`

then set z to `z - x+(x*1.15)+(x*1.15*1.15)+(x*1.15*1.15*1.15)+(x*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15)+(x*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15)+(x*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15)+(x*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15)+(x*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15)+(x*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15)`

Change cps (cookies per second) by `10 * a` (the amount of cookies per second that is being changed by multiplied by 10. I usually just add an extra 0 to the end of the number for simplicity)

Set b(y) (the cost of the building that is being bought) by `(x*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15*1.15)`

Change y by 10

else

broadcast Can't Buy!

However, I want to write as a cumulative price, similar to the formula used to determine how many cookies you would need to buy x buildings when you have y amount of the building such as `bΣ(b=a+1) ((c)(1.15^b))/1.15` where `c` is the base cost of the type building you want to buy, `b` is the number of the type of building you want to have, and `a` is the number of the type of building you have currently.

To clear up any confusion, if you want to take a look at the editor, [here is the link.](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/814368636/editor/)

Comment: `I don't want to have the code as x+(x1.15)+(x1.15^2)+...+(x*1.15^99` that's what loops are for though. You can keep incrementing the exponent in a loop. But you can skip loops altogether by finding the equivalent equation on, say, Wolfram Alpha. So if I plug in `sum x * (1.15^n), n = 0 .. y`, the result is `1/3 (-20 + 20^(-y) 23^(1 + y)) x`. So, there's no need to sum anything in that case. You can skip the sum and any loops by just plugging your values in directly to that equivalent equation. Something like `bΣ(b=a+1) ((c)(1.15^b))/1.15` you can probably also play with on Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: @RandomDavis Thank you. This is honestly very useful, however wouldn't I still have to code a custom block for exponentiation on both sides of the "^" function since Scratch only allows for the "e^_ "and "10^_" function, seeing I'd have to input 20 to the power of and 23 to the power of?

Comment: Well to do `23^(1 + y)`, Since `y` is an integer, you can do a loop of 23*23 and just repeat `1 - y` times.

Comment: There's also various ways to compute exponents without having the function be implemented in the language itself. This answer talks about how to calculate negative exponents, and do something called "exponentiation by squaring": https://stackoverflow.com/a/62379518/6273251

Comment: @CrSb0001; You might find useful the [Scratch Workaround Guide](https://scratch.mit.edu/discuss/topic/611582/) from the official Scratch Discussion Forums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used that C program link I sent you, for how to compute powers, to write an equivalent function in Scratch. Works with both positive and negative exponents. I'm rusty with Scratch so there might be a better way to return from the function, but it seems like it works great.

This should be all you need in order to get going, but if you still run into issues I can try to help out:

[image: Power Function]

Result:

[image]

Proof:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The process is less clunky now, and sure by all means it only took the count down ~80 blocks (mainly because I created another custom block to read the value of the current cost), it absolutely works!

Comment: Awesome. Scratch does have limitations but usually there's _some_ way to achieve what you want without a ton of repetition.

Comment: At least it is less messy than doing "x*(y^z)+x*(y^(z+1))+...+x*(y^(z+n))" haha

Comment: Yeah. I highly recommend seeing if you can use loops to avoid any kind of repetition you might still have. Also I still recommend looking up equivalent equations on Wolfram Alpha to see if there's simplified versions.

Answer (score 1):

The sum you are trying to solve is a special case of something known as a finite geometric series and it's formula is:

[image]

latex:`\sum_{k=0}^n xy^k=\frac{xy^{n+1}-x}{y-1}`

plugging the values in we get:

[image]

latex:`\sum_{k=0}^{100} x(1.15)^k=x\frac{(1.15)^{101}-1}{0.15}=20x\frac{(1.15)^{101}-1}{3}`

to compute (1.15)^{101} we can use the fact that the exponential function and logarithm are inverses of each other to get that

[image]

latex:`(1.15)^{101}=e^{101\log(1.15)}`

writing this in scratch we get

[image]

Wolframalpha gives an approximation of 1350460.46830533172615525572988868491474851495179481437632719

more generally, if x is the initial number of buildings and n is the number of buildings to be bought, then the sum in scratch can be computed using
[image]