# How do I write factorials in Scratch?

Tags: limit, summary, mit-scratch

So I was taking a break from my [PvZ project in Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/844867116/) and trying to see what I could do in Scratch. So here's the thing: I sort of wanted to see if I could make a converter from say, sin(x°) to sin(x<sup>radians</sup>), which shouldn't be too hard, except here's the thing: sin(x<sup>radians</sup>) is `sin(πx°/180)`
Now here's where problems arise, because here is a representation of π:

```html
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
  tex2jax: {inlineMath: [["$","$"]]},
  CommonHTML: {
    scale: 120
  }
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" async src=
"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/latest.js?config=
TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>
$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{50k-6}{2^k\binom{3k}k}$
```

Which in turn simplifies to

```html
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
  tex2jax: {inlineMath: [["$","$"]]},
  CommonHTML: {
    scale: 120
  }
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" async src=
"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/latest.js?config=
TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>
$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{k!(2k)!(50k-6)}{2^k(3k)!}$
```

---

---

#### Now here's my problem:

---

---

How would I format this in Scratch, since there's no code block for Scratch that would allow me to do this. The only workaround that I could possibly see happening is if somehow, there was a way to create summation and products in Scratch. Even in my [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75698062/is-there-a-way-to-write-summation-using-scratch) question on this site where I was wondering what I would be able to do since there wasn't a way to represent summation, it just turns out that the best that I could do would be something like this:

---

Raising stuff to a power code:

```
[scratchblocks]
define pow(base)(power)
set [result v] to [1]
set [base v] to (base)
set [power v] to (round (power))
set [done v] to [0]
if <(power) < [0]> then
set [base v] to [((1) / (base))]
set [power v] to [-1(() *(round (power))]
end
repeat until <[done v] = [1]>
if <(([power v]) mod (2)) = [0]> then
set [result v] to (([result v]) * ([base v]))
change [power v] by (-1)
end
if <(([power v]) mod (2)) > [0]> then
set [done v] to [1]
end
if <<not <<[done v] = [1]>>>
set [base v] to (([base v]) * ([base v]))
set [power v] to (([power v]) / (2))
end
end
[/scratchblocks]
```

---

And even then, if I want to write summation, I have to write the exponentiation individually, which honestly is just extremely annoying in my opinion. In fact, if you do want to see how it's written out, [here](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/814368636/editor/) is the link to the Scratch project that I asked about in my first ever question.

> And just so people don't get angry and say that it's annoyingly difficult to find, a quick way to find it is by clicking on the "Buy 10 (cursorSprite1" sprite (which this isn't even a typo, this is actually how the sprite name would be typed out)

---

In fact, the only way I can think of even attempting to write this out would be like how the summation is written out: Looks simple, but has to be extremely complex just for it to work in a simple way. There would have to be a lot of variables/messages going out at the same time, and that would cause a great deal of lag. And I'm not even needing that much precision (only a sum from k=0 to 13), so it seems that it would only be trying to get factorials to work being an honest pain in the butt.

---

---

#### My question

---

---

Is there a way that I could create factorials in Scratch, or if not, why and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to calculate factorials in Scratch.

Think about how factorials are really calculated. You start at n and go down by one until you hit one, each time multiplying the your new number (eg: 3!=3x2x1)

This can be replicated in Scratch quite easily:

Scratchblocks format:

```
[scratchblocks]
when green flag clicked
ask [enter value for n] and wait
return=(answer)!
say (join (join (answer) [!=]) (return))
stop [all v]
[/scratchblocks]
 
[scratchblocks]
define return=(n)!
set [index v] to (n)
set [return v] to [1]
repeat ((n))
set [return v] to (([return]) * ([index]))
change [index v] by (-1)
end
[/scratchblocks]
```

https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/939563834/

Comment: Well, this is fascinating! I'll edit in the [scratchblocks] for you. Edit: when the [pending edits queue is not full lol](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84362/whats-the-fixed-size-of-the-suggested-edit-queue)

Comment: actually [here's the scratchblocks](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/939600593/) format if you would want to edit this in

Comment: Thanks! Is there anywhere where I could learn [scratchblocks]?

Comment: The [scratch discussion forum probably](https://scratch.mit.edu/discuss/)

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**
No, there is no built-in factorial function.
But even if there were such a function, why would you need it here?

First of all, when you need π in an application (as in your case, to convert between degrees and radials), you are not going to *calculate* π.
Instead, you just define a constant with the hardcoded value 3.141592653589793.
This has three important advantages:

1. Performance: hardcoding π is a lot more efficient than calculating π.
2. Accuracy: rounding errors will accumulate during your calculation, given the limited accuracy of the floating-point numbers used in almost every programming language, including Scratch.
3. Simplicity: in application code, this calculation is basically just clutter.

Even if you would insist on having π calculated,
it makes more sense to use the built-in `arctan` function,
for the same three reasons: performance, accuracy, simplicity.

[image: pi=4*arctan(1)]

If you insist on doing the calculation using only very basic math operations,
this wiki article suggests to use the [Leibniz formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80):

https://en.scratch-wiki.info/wiki/Calculating_Pi

Of course, it makes total sense to write your own calculation, but only **out of mathematical curiosity or as a coding exercise.**
Please keep in mind that *n*! will overflow for *n* greater than 170.
Consequently, this will overflow for *k* > 56:

[image: naive implementation]

Whereas this will take much longer to overflow.

[image: efficient implementation]

You can even combine this with taking the power of 2.

[image: combined with power]

In pseudo code:

```
denominator = 1
a = 6 * k
b = k
do k times
    denominator = denominator * (a / b)
    a = a - 2
    b = b - 1
```

Comment: So in other words, if I did want to calculate π, I should use `4*arctan(1)` since according to the formula, `arctan(1)=π/4`?